# pgf plot: Missing number, treated as zero

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to plot `cos(ln(x))` using `pgfplots` but I get this strange error that I cannot figure out.

Below is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin = 1, xmax = 2]

\addplot[blue, samples=50]{ ln(x)             };
\addplot[red, samples=50]{ cos(deg(x))        };

\addplot[green, samples=50]{ cos(deg(ln(x))   };

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The errors come from line: `\addplot[green, samples=50]{ cos(deg(ln(x))   };` and are the following:

> line 14: Missing number, treated as zero. ...ot[green, samples=50]{
>   cos(deg(ln(x)) };
>
> line 14: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). ...ot[green,
>   samples=50]{ cos(deg(ln(x)) };

I am very confused since plotting `ln(x)` and `cos(deg(x))` does not return any errors. And `ln(x)` is perfectly well behaved on 1 to 2...

Comment: Very similar question here https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/303069/117534. You need to define a domain, otherwise it defaults to -5:5

Comment: Indeed, the question is identical.
(strange I didn't come across it in my half hour google search...)

mods may feel free to delete my post :)

Comment: There's a subtlety here. Your question also mentions about `ln(x)`. It begs the question why `ln(x)` doesn't throw an error (I'm not sure, which is why I left a comment, not an answer). I think this is worthy of a question, and enough of a subtle difference to warrant a non-duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the error because you try to evaluate `cos(deg(ln(x)))` for negative values of `x`, where the solutions of `ln(x)` are complex numbers, and `ln(0)` where it is -∞ (`-inf`). It seems `deg` can handle these values, but `cos` cannot, for reasons unbeknownst to me.

The reason this is no problem with only `ln(x)` is that `pgfplots` has the inital setting `unbounded coords=discard`, which means it drops the value if it evaluates to ±∞ (`+inf` or `-inf`) or if it is `nan` ("not a number"). This does not work for `cos(deg(ln(x)))`, since you are trying to calculate `cos(nan)` or `cos(-inf)`, which is why the error is raised only at the last plot.

This happens because you are not specifying a `domain` for the plot, meaning it will use the default domain `-5:5`.

So by specifying `domain=1:2` in your axis (or only for the last plot):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin = 1, xmax = 2,domain=1:2]

\addplot[blue, samples=50]{ ln(x)             };
\addplot[red, samples=50]{ cos(deg(x))        };
\addplot[green, samples=50]{ cos(deg(ln(x)))  };

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Output]

Comment: Oh I thought that xmin=1, xmax = 2 took care of that...
Than you for the input :)

Comment: `xmin` and `xmax` are just the boundaries for the displayed axis.

Comment: It does beg the question why `ln(x)` doesn't throw an error even with no domain specified. I feel the answer should address that as well (?)

Comment: @Troy See updated answer. At least that is the reason as far as I can understand.

Comment: @hooy did you try plotting `deg(ln(x))`? It works for me, without a domain specified. you might be close with an explanation though.. hmm.

Comment: @Troy Hm, you are right. Seems `cos` of `nan` and `-inf` is the culprit. Plotting `deg(nan)` and `deg(-inf)` works, but `cos(nan)` and `cos(-inf)` does not.